# Does a body with constant force have a constant acceleration?

Tags: linear-algebra

When we say that a body applies 20 N Force on a body of mass 10kg on a horizontal plane.
Acceleration comes out to be 2m/s2.Does it mean that the velocity of the body keeps changing and may change to even 100m/s or there would be other forces too which would make the body speed up a constant rate.(If we consider a horizontal , inclined or free fall condition).

Comment: Questions such as these are better suited to the [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all forces have been accounted for, if your **net** force does not equal zero then the body in question will experience a change in velocity over a period of time, until another force presents itself and acts upon the body, this is acceleration.

To answer your question, yes, this acceleration of $2ms^{-2}$ will cause the body's velocity to increase at a constant rate. If we were, for example, in space, and we set our body off in a given direction in which it will experience no external forces other than the one we have given it, it will increase at a constant rate forever, even well beyond $100ms^{-1}$. Generally speaking though, in most question you will have some friction of opposing force to account for which will reduce the body's acceleration. I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help, also if you want to mark this question as answered you just have to click on the tick next to my answer :)